# How is SystemVerilog 0 different from '0?

Tags: system-verilog

When executing the following piece of SystemVerilog code (compiled and run with Questa)

```
bit [7:0] test = 255;
$display("%b %b %b", test,        test == 255,      test == '1);
$display("%b %b %b", ~test,       ~test == 0,       ~test == '0);
$display("%b %b %b", 8'b00000000, 8'b00000000 == 0, 8'b00000000 == '0);
```

the output is

```
11111111 1 1
00000000 0 1
00000000 1 1
```

My question is about the 2nd number on the 2nd output line: How is binary `00000000` different from 0?  And why is it only different if it is the result of `~test`, and not when it is a literal?  Is this a Questa bug or a property of the language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that `0`, without any width prefix defaults to 32-bit value. In an equality, the operands get sized to the maximum width between the expressions on the LHS and RHS expressions before evaluating those expressions.  Try `~test == 9'h0` and `~test == 9'h100` and see what you get.

The size of `'0` is based on its context. So `~test =='0` become `~test == 8'b0` in that context.

Comment: So you're saying that (in your 9-bit example) `test` gets expanded to `9'h0ff` and then inverted to `9'h100`?

I was considering something like this but I was assuming it would first calculate `~test` (which would be `8'h00`) and then expand that to `9'h000`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. See _11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression_ in the 1800-2012 LRM.

Comment: I would hardly consider that to be a feature but maybe that's personal taste... Thanks for explaining!